# no data retrieve when getting data from firebase using stream builder and where clause

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting no data when using this code, i noticed that this code work when I do .doc() instead of .where()

so how to make where clause work with map method

```
new StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("purchasedItems").where('paymentID', isEqualTo: "Jdc2kAoMVQq0AfcoS0uO").snapshots().map(DatabaseService().purchasedItemfromSnapshot),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Container();
    }
    List<PurchasedItem> items = snapshot.data.docs;
    return ListView.builder(...)
})
```

the map function:

```
List<PurchasedItem> purchasedItemfromSnapshot (QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return PurchasedItem(
        purchasedItemID: doc.id,
        paymentID: data['paymentID'],
        purchasedItemName: data['purchasedItemName'],
        price: data['price'],
        purchasedItemCurrency: data['purchasedItemCurrency']
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `docs` instance in `snapshot.data.docs`.

Just assign  `List<PurchasedItem> items = snapshot.data`

Other than that your code should work. This is another way to use `Stream`. Try this way.

**Stream Function**

```dart
Stream<List< PurchasedItem>> getItems(String id) {
   var ref = _db.collection('purchasedItems').where('paymentID', isEqualTo: id);
    
   return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => PurchasedItem.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
}
```

**Model Class**

```dart
class PurchasedItem {
    
   final String purchasedItemID, purchasedItemName;
    
   PurchasedItem({this.purchasedItemID,this.purchasedItemName});
    
 factory PurchasedItem.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   
   Map data = doc.data();
    
   return PurchasedItem(
       purchasedItemID: doc.id,
     //paymentID: data['paymentID'],
       purchasedItemName: data['purchasedItemName'],
     //price: data['price'],
     //purchasedItemCurrency: data['purchasedItemCurrency']
 );}
}
```

**StreamBuilder Widget**

```dart
StreamBuilder<List<PurchasedItem>>(
  stream: getItems('Jdc2kAoMVQq0AfcoS0uO'),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Container();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot?.data?.length ?? 0,
        itemBuilder:(_, int index) {
         final PurchasedItem data = snapshot.data[index];
         return Text(data.purchasedItemName);
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: I did it before i try .docs and didnt work

Comment: your code should work. I tried your code.

Comment: Please filter `paymentID` with `Jdc2kAoMVQq0AfcoS0uO ` from firebase console and find out it is working or not

Comment: @esraakd I added another way to approach your work. Try this one too.

Comment: sorry my code just worked, its my fault i used double price in my model and firebase it was int :( very sorry for that